# Unsure about the type of Shell Commands

Tags: python, shell, command

If I see commands like the one shown in the following screenshot and the one appended after that, does it mean it is run in **Windows** Command Prompt?  I'm confused because I think commands in Windows Command Prompt have `>` instead of `$`, and it doesn't look like **IPython** Console shell under **Spyder** either.

```sh
$ pip install virtualenv
```

```sh
$ mkdir python-virtual-environments && cd python-virtual-environments
```

Comment: This would be run in something like the bash shell. This is installed by default on Linux and most other Unix-like systems, but under Windows equivalents are available as gitbash or Cygwin. The `$` represents the prompt here.

Comment: The first one will install virtualenv and the second one will create a new folder called python-virtual-environments and then move into it.

Answer (score 0):

This what you see in Linux terminals : `user@ubuntu$`

and in Windows you see :`C:\users\user>`

You can use the pip and py, python from the command prompt if you had selected add python to system path if not you can navigate to:

> Programs and Features -> Uninstall a program

Here select Python and click change and there you can select an option to add it system environment variable, if not you can do by adding the Python scripts directory to system variable.

So, coming to your concern you can always use pip and py or python in cmd of windows and terminal of Linux

Comment: Please refrain from writing stylised all-lower-case posts here - this is not a chatroom.